# how to delete Windows 10 task bar list of recent items for Word or other tasks

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, taskbar

I can't figure out how to clear the list of "Recent" items that pops up when I right-click a task, especially Microsoft Word, on the Windows 10 task bar.

I tried deleting users\me\appdata\Roaming\Microsoft\windows\RecentData\ but that didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the recent items that appear when you right hand click on an application you need to delete the contents of this folder:

C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations

This is also accessible using the AppData environmental variable:

%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations

Hope this helps.